# What is the most efficient (in terms of speed and number of lines) way to replace a file content by another file content in Bash?

Tags: bash

File A (`a.txt`) contains integers in each line, where the integer ranges from 1 to K:

```
1
5
4
2
6
...
```

File B (`b.txt`) contains arbitrary strings in each line, and the number of lines is exactly K:

```
Sports
World
Finance
Politics
...
```

The goal here is to replace each line in `a.txt` by retrieving corresponding line index from `b.txt`.

Now if I were to use python to achieve this goal, I would construct a dictionary from `b.txt` and simply map each value in `a.txt` using the dictionary.

What would be the best way to achieve the same goal using Bash scripts?

Comment: Wouldn't it be more intuitive to use a list than a dict?

Answer (score 2):

Read `b.txt` into an array with `mapfile`, then use the values in `a.txt` as indexes into that array.

```
# read b.txt into array b_data
mapfile b_data < b.txt

while read index; do
  echo "${b_data[index]}"
done < a.txt > new_a.txt
```

And then rename `new_a.txt` to `a.txt` if that's your goal.

Comment: You need to use `mapfile -t` to avoid extra newlines, and `"${b_data[index-1]}"` because bash arrays are 0-indexed (i.e. they start at 0 rather than 1).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=$0;next} {print a[$0]}' file2 file1
```

This `awk` script first reads the file with the descriptions and store them in array, then parses the file with the numbers and prints the corresponding lines.

Comment: Will this method be faster than the `mapfile` method?

Comment: This is probably faster, because the bash-only solution I posted involves a shell `while` loop, but unless you have a very large input set I suspect you'd have a hard time spotting the difference.